# display an image stored in the database with Java

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I have a problem when I want to display an image stored in the database with OLE using JAVA.

Comment: I think you should add more information to your question :)
What is the problem? An exception? you just don't know how to do it?

Comment: yes I don't know how to display the image from the database.

Comment: Do you know how to display an image of any kind? Is it the loading that is the problem, or is it the "showing"?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but you should read this: [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: Acharf: But are you able to read it?

Answer (score 2):

If your image data is stored in your database as some blob, you would probably want to use an [`ImageIcon`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/) and construct it using the `byte[] imageData` constructor:

> `ImageIcon(byte[] imageData)`
>
> > Creates an ImageIcon from an array of bytes which were read from an image file containing a supported image format, such as GIF, JPEG, or (as of 1.3) PNG.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to do a good guess, I would say you have to read it from the database using a blob, something like:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT imageblob FROM YOUR_TABLE where id = ?");
pstmt.setInt( 1, imageId );
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
byte[]data = null;
while( rs.next() ) {
    data = rs.getBlob(1).getBytes();
}
```

And then displaying it with a servlet by writing the data to the output stream.

```
....

response.setContentType("image/jpg");
response.getOutputStream().write(data,0,data.length );
response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

But this is just a guess, because your question lack of essential information.

Here's are some links related to Blob  and Servlets

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/BlobJDBCdealswithBinaryData.htm

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/blob.html

http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/retreiveimage.shtml

I hope this helps